# Check to avoid adding multiple items to canvas in WPF/C#

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

```
Shape shape = sm.maakEllips();
if (!canvas.Children.Contains(shape))
{
    cm.Draw(shape, canvas, locatie);
}

public void Draw(Shape vorm, Canvas canvas, Point locatie)
{
    if (vorm.Height <= canvas.Height && vorm.Width <= canvas.Width)
    {
        Canvas.SetTop(vorm, locatie.Y);
        Canvas.SetLeft(vorm, locatie.X);
        canvas.Children.Add(vorm);
    }
}
```

So I add a shape to a canvas in the Draw(). Then when I check on this in the upper if clause, I'm still able to add the same shape to the same canvas multiple times.
I don't get it, what am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

```
            Shape shape = sm.makeShape(Convert.ToByte(textboxR.Text), Convert.ToByte(textboxG.Text), Convert.ToByte(textboxB.Text), Convert.ToInt32(textboxHoogte.Text), Convert.ToInt32(textboxBreedte.Text));
            foreach (Shape existingShape in canvas.Children.OfType<Shape>())
            {
                if (existingShape.Width != shape.Width && existingShape.Height != shape.Height
                    && existingShape.Fill != shape.Fill)
                {
                    cm.Draw(shape, canvas, locatie);
                }
            }
```

I tried this and now I'm not even able to add a shape to the canvas at all.
I don't see what I'm doing wrong at all.

Comment: When you create a new shape that hasn't been added to the Canvas yet, it will never be a child of the Canvas already. Or are you not actually creating a new shape? Are you really asking us what `maakEllips()` does?

Comment: I think he tries to check if a shape of type Ellipse has already been added to the canvas or not.
If so, you have 2 ways to do it. Either you keep a list of the type of shapes you already added and use it as a reference before adding more, or you loop through the existing shapes in the canvas and compare their type to what you do not want duplicated.

Comment: Do I need to use a loop? Isn't using 'Children.Contains' enough to check if the shape already exists in the canvas?

Comment: How can I check if a particular shape exists in a canvas without using a list? Is the way I do it wrong?

Comment: As already said, a newly created Shape is never already a child of the Canvas. Two Shapes with the same properties and the same position are still two Shapes, and not "the same". Your question makes no sense.

Comment: But I add the shape to the canvas.Children in the draw(). But as I understand I need to make a foreach loop and compare the properties of each shape in the canvas instead of only comparing 2 shapes?

Comment: Have you solved the Q?

Answer (score 1):

Your `Draw()` method add `vorm` of type `Shape` to the canvas specified in `canvas`. And I assume your `sm.maakEllips()` returns an ellipse.

Therefore, when you run the following code:

```
Shape shape = sm.maakEllips();
if (!canvas.Children.Contains(shape))
{
    cm.Draw(shape, canvas, locatie);
}
```

You will go inside the `if` statement **only** if the canvas contains that exact `shape` object you created in the line above, using `sm.maakEllips()` method. It cannot be **any** shape that has the same properties of the `shape` object above. Because, every time you create a new object, even with the exact same properties including its name, they are still two distinct objects in `.NET` world.

To illustrate the point see the code sample below.

Your unchanged `Draw()` method:

```
public void Draw(Shape vorm, Canvas canvas, Point locatie)
{
    if (vorm.Height <= canvas.Height && vorm.Width <= canvas.Width)
    {
        Canvas.SetTop(vorm, locatie.Y);
        Canvas.SetLeft(vorm, locatie.X);
        canvas.Children.Add(vorm);
    }
}
```

A `makeEllipse()` method that creates an ellipse of width and height of 100 and 80 respectively, and assigns the `name` passed in the parameter.

```
public Shape makeEllipse(string name)
{
    Shape sh = new Ellipse
    {
        Name = name,
        Width = 100,
        Height = 80,
    };
    return sh;
}
```

Now see the following code, executed at the click of a button.

```
private void btnGO_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Creates an ellipse with name "Shape1", and assigns to sh1.
    Shape sh1 = makeEllipse("Shape1");

    // Adds the said sh1 to the canvas using `Draw()` method.
    Draw(sh1, myCanvas, new Point(5, 5));

    // See if sh1 exists as a child of `myCanvas`.
    // Since sh1 is now a child of canvas, code does NOT go inside the if-clause.
    if (!myCanvas.Children.Contains(sh1))
    {
        Draw(sh1, myCanvas, new Point(5, 5));
    }

    // Creates an ellipse with the same name "Shape1", and assigns to sh2.
    Shape sh2 = makeEllipse("Shape1");

    // It is NOT added to the canvas using `Draw()` method.

    // Now, here, code DOES go inside the if-clause, because the said object does not exist as a child of `myCanvas`.
    if (!myCanvas.Children.Contains(sh2))
    {
        Draw(sh2, myCanvas, new Point(5, 5));
    }
}
```

Comments above should be good enough, but to explain again,

- When you create `sh1` and adds it to `myCanvas` using `Draw()` method, it becomes a child element of `myCanvas.Children`.
- Then, when you check if it is a child using `if (!myCanvas.Children.Contains(sh1))`, since it IS a child element by that time, condition becomes `false` and we do not go inside the `if` clause.
- Next, we create `sh2`, which has the exact same dimensions and the name as `sh1`. However, and this is the key, `.NET` treats it as a different object even though it has the same properties as the previous object. Reason being, whenever we use the `new` keyword, `.NET` creates an actual new object.
- Afterwards, we DON'T add it to the canvas using `Draw()` method.
- Now, at the second `if` when we check if `myCanvas` contains the object, it finds that `sh2` is NOT a child of `myCanvas`, so it goes inside the `if` clause.

Answer (score 1):

`maakEllips()` always creates a new `Shape`. If you want to compare this one against other `Shape` elements in the `Canvas`, you need to iterate through these. The following code compares the height, width and position and adds the new `Shape` to the `Canvas` if any of them differ:

```
Shape shape = sm.maakEllips();
foreach (Shape existingShape in canvas.Children.OfType<Shape>())
{
    if(existingShape.Width != canvas.Width || existingShape.Height != canvas.Height 
        || Canvas.GetLeft(existingShape) != Canvas.GetLeft(shape)
        || Canvas.GetTop(existingShape) != Canvas.GetTop(shape))
    {
        cm.Draw(shape, canvas, locatie);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks already for the help.
I did it different, but something similar to this. And it still doesn't work.
I check for every child in the canvas (only shapes will be added) if the width, the heigth and the color are the same. If it is so, I shouldn't be able to add the shape to the canvas.

What happens now, is that I can't add a shape anymore at all. In the edit section you can find my code. What am I doing wrong?